# Conflict with Accessible Keyboard Menus

Tags: wordpress, extension

I'm in Wordpress 5.2 and the Civi menus disappeared. I brought up my inspector and isolated the problem to Keyboard Accessible Menus (KAM). The fallout there is that CiviTutorial and Recent Items Menu have dependencies on KAM. There were a handful of minor security related updates that followed WP 5.2. I'm not sure what else might have interacted with KAM, but it's managed to kill about 1/3 of my day.

Other than, am I alone with this problem, am I looking at bigger issue when KAM integrates into core?

Comment: KAM is already integrated into the current release of core.  What version are you using?

Comment: I'm on 5.11.0. Is the extension, which I don't want, installing for these other extensions and creating a conflict?

Comment: It was moved to core in 5.12.0 and enhanced in 5.13.0. Might be worth asking on chat about conflicts with WP5.2, but there's a comment there saying 'working fine'